# Is it possible to configure Kafka topic-level configuration programmatically when using Akka-Streams-Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream

I would like to add topics dynamically in Akka-Streams-Kafka. As I understand Kafka has four levels of configuration: Broker, Topic, Consumer and Producer. Consumer and Producer levels can be configured programmatically using constructors:

```
def withProperty(key: value: String): ConsumerSettings[K, V]
def withProperty(key: String, value: String): ProducerSettings[K, V]
```

However, Broker-level configuration I always did via Apache Kafka config/server.properties and Topic Configuration upon topic creation using [Apache Kafka server](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topic-config):

1)Is there a way to do Topic-level configuration programatically in Akka-Streams-Kafka? I can do topic-level configuration in [Embedded-Kafka](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka) library when testing

2) Is it a good idea to have topics added dynamically/programatically, potentially increasing large number of topics,few thousands?

3) how can I remove a topics dynamically/programatically? is it removed from Kafka when it has no subscribers for some time

Comment: What version of Kafka are you running?

Comment: I am running the latest 0.11 Kafka version

Comment: It depends on how you want your client to react when you add new topics. If you want your client to detect new topics and connect to it, you could do that probably.